# PHP Math Pythagoras

Tags: php, math, pythagorean

Okay, I've coded this pythagoras-solver kind of thing, and I was wondering any ways I could improve it, or make it more efficient?

```
<?php
    $sides = array('1' => 'Hypotenuse',
        '2' => 'Adjacent',
        '3' => 'Opposite');

    function createSideDropdown($name) {
        global $sides;
        $option = "<select name='".$name."'>";
            if(!empty($sides)) {
                foreach($sides as $id => $sideDesc) {
                    $option .= "<option value='".$id."'>".$sideDesc."</option>";
                }
            } else {
                die("Error fetching sides!");
            }
        $option .= "</select>";
        echo $option;
    }

    try {
        if(!empty($_POST['submit'])) {
            if(empty($_POST['val1']) || empty($_POST['val2'])) {
                throw new Exception("Please enter an integer in both boxes.");
            }
            if(!is_numeric($_POST['val1']) || !is_numeric($_POST['val2'])) {
                throw new Exception("One of the numbers you entered is not a valid integer.");
            }

            $val1 = $_POST['val1'];
            $val2 = $_POST['val2'];
            $val1numtype = $_POST['val1type'];
            $val2numtype = $_POST['val2type'];
            $val1nametype = $sides[$val1numtype];
            $val2nametype = $sides[$val2numtype];

                if($val1numtype == $val2numtype) {
                    throw new Exception("The two sides of the triangle must be different");
                }

                if($val1nametype == "Hypotenuse" || $val2nametype == "hypotenuse") {
                    // work out a small side
                    $bignum = max($val1, $val2);
                    $smallnum = min($val1, $val2);
                    $sqTotal = ($bignum * $bignum) - ($smallnum * $smallnum);
                    $total = sqrt($sqTotal);
                    echo $bignum."&sup2; - ".$smallnum."&sup2; = ".$sqTotal."<br />
                    &radic;".$sqTotal." = ".$total.$_POST['mes'];
                } else {
                    // work out the hypotenuse
                    $sq1 = $val1 * $val1;
                    $sq2 = $val2 * $val2;
                    $sqTotal = $sq1 + $sq2;
                    $total = sqrt($sqTotal);
                    echo $val1."&sup2; + ".$val2."&sup2; = ".$sqTotal."<br />
                    &radic;".$sqTotal." = ".$total.$_POST['mes'];
                }       
            echo "<br /><br />"; // Seperate the working out from the input
        }
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage()."<br/><br/>";
    }


?>
<form method='POST' action='index.php'>
Value 1: <input type='text' name='val1' /> 
<?php createSideDropdown("val1type"); ?>
<br /><br />

Value 2: <input type='text' name='val2' /> 
<?php createSideDropdown("val2type"); ?>
<br />
<select name="mes">
<option name="mm">mm</option>
<option name="cm">cm</option>
<option name="m">m</option>
<option name="cm">km</option>
</select>
<br /> 

<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one thing you can certainly do is:

HTML on its own and PHP on its own - separate that. And then, I would continue having a look at the rest.

Also, you could do your exceptions with JavaScript - I mean, use JavaScript to parse the text fields and write the errors with JavaScript. Rather than always submitting the form. - Still you should parse the fields in PHP as well.

Then, make a class out of it and make a proper documentation of it such as

```
/**
 * This method does bla
 * @param Int a
 */
```

Don't use globals - could be done with class attributes.

Comment: Thanks.
Got any resources about commenting standards? I've seen @param and stuff around but never researched it.

Comment: Because this is a beginner question I would add the usual reason for performing validity checks both in JavaScript on the client and in PHP (or whatever) on the server is: Checking on the client usually leads to a better user experience, but checking on the server is still required because any client might be used to submit to the server. Only the server code is (possibly) secure so security checks must be done server side (though you can redundantly implement security checks client side if it will improve User Experience).